# How to make Mysql/Mariadb script work at bootup in debian?

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, mariadb, systemd

I am trying to run a script at bootup which outputs a file from database and saves it in a directory. My script works fine in shell, but fails when I try to use systemd for running the script at boot up.

Following is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -u user -p123 <<EOF
use database
SELECT data INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/file1.txt' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '' LINES TERMINATED BY "\n" FROM datalog;
EOF
```

My systemd service is like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=My service
After=mysql.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/myscript.sh start
StandardOutput=null

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=myscript.service
```

My service status shows as inactive(dead). I even tried changing my service Type to forking and oneshot but nothing works.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

**Edit**: After running `sudo journalctl -u myservice` I got this:

```
May 08 15:02:02 beaglebone systemd[1]: Started My service.                    
May 08 15:02:02 beaglebone sudo[3003]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=roo          
May 08 15:02:02 beaglebone sudo[3003]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened fo          
May 08 15:02:02 beaglebone sudo[3003]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed fo
```

Comment: What does `sudo journalctl -u myscript` show?

Comment: @ManuelSchmidt please see my edit.

Comment: Could you try adding `Requires=mysql.service` after `After=mysql.service`, please?

Comment: `Type=oneshot` also would seem to be more appropriate for a process that doesn't' stick around.

Comment: @ManuelSchmidt After adding Requires, it works when I start the service but its not working on boot up even though its enabled.

Comment: @danblack I don't see a difference in Type=oneshot or Type=simple here. Its not working at boot up with both options.

Answer (score 0):

`Exec` isn't a directive, you probably mean `ExecStart`

Comment: Tried with ExecStart but still inactive(dead)